# Proving eigenvalues are 1 and -1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a matrix $A$ is symmetric and orthogonal, prove that the only possible eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$. I know that $A$ is Diagonalizable such that there is a matrix $P$ such that $P^TAP = D$. Where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with only $1$ or $-1$ as entries.  Not sure where to go from here

Comment: Similar matrices have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: Have you seen the theorems that (1) eigenvalues of orthogonal matrices are complex numbers of absolute value $1$, and (2) eigenvalues of real symmetric matrices are real? If so, you can just combine them.

Comment: No I haven't seen those theorems do you have links to them?

Comment: @GregBrown Your matrix $P$ is orthogonal, i.e., $P^T = P^{-1}$. Now, taking Joe's comment into account, do you see why the only eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is orthogonal , then $AA^{T}=I$ , where $A^{T}$  is the transpose of $A$. Now , you know that $DetA=DetA^{T}$ , so that  $DetI=DetADetA^{T}$.... Now, apply results of the finite-dimensional version of the spectral theorem about modulus of eigenvalues, and about the fact that the eigenvalues are Real (though their names have been changed to protect the innocent) .

Comment: Determinant is the product of all eigenvalues. It gives you no information on each individual eigenvalue. For example, $D = \operatorname{diag}(2,1/2)$ will also have determinant equal to $1$, but it doesn't have eigenvalues equal to $\pm 1$.

Comment: Oh, yes, I misread, again, only for the 500th time. Let me rewrite.

Comment: @Vedran Sego: I included the finite dimensional spectral theorem, re eigenvalues having modulus 1 and being Real --or at least keeping it Real.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A^2 - I =0$, and $X^2 -1$ is a polynom with simple roots $-1$ and $1$.